# While creating custom grid in magento 2 error showing 404 Error Page not found.Actually i following mageplaza tutorial here

Tags: custom

Here I am using mageplaza link ie  https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

Actually i copied whole content as it is including model as well.but its showing error only **404 Error Page not found.**

Comment: Can you please add your code what you have tried?

Comment: logout from admin panel and then login into the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is due to routing or controller